# How to convert hand-written text in image on Android or Java app?

Tags: java, android, converters, ocr

I have a problem with OCR to convert text in Android. My app can get text from picture but only with words printing from a computer, with hand-written, it can't convert right word. Please help me solved it.

**This is my code**

```
private void scanImage(AppCompatButton button) {
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tessBaseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
            tessBaseApi.init(datapath, lang);
            tessBaseApi.setImage(bitmap);
            String result = tessBaseApi.getUTF8Text();
            tv_scan.setText(result);
           // ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Converting...", "Detecting text from image...", true);
            tessBaseApi.end();
        }
    });
}
```

I use with japanese library to detect handwritting, but it can't although it can recognize computer words.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Android or Java. It is an issue of your OCR engine. It has to be capable of recognizing handwriting. Maybe it has to be configured to do so.

Comment: Which OCR do you use?